# как отменить слияние моей master ветки с удаленной

Tags: git, git-merge

закоммитил изменения и запушил свою ветку master и забыл, что оно пойдёт сразу же в удаленную ветку master без всяких мерж реквестов... как можно отменить слияние? просто хочу полностью его убрать на удаленнке

Comment: Создаете временную ветку на текущем коммите, чтобы его не потерять. Делаете из мастера `git reset --hard` на предыдущий коммит, потом force push в мастер, и такой же reset обратно. Потом удаляете временную ветку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. На текущем положении своей ветки master создаёте другую ветку.
2. `git reset`ом сбрасываете положение локальной ветки master на последний коммит, который должен остаться в удалённой.
3. `gut push --force`

Для 3-го шага, возможно, потребуется вмешательство администратора репозитория, так как ветка master чаще всего защищена от force-пуша.

PS если с репозиторием работают множество людей, то нужно чтоб каждый кто уже успел сделать `pull`/`fetch` тоже откатил свою копию ветки master

Comment: для третьего шага я сам настройки изменил, думаю, никто не будет против
спасибо вам большое, я чуть с ума не сошёл вчера пока пытался сам че то придумать...
у меня там ещё была проблема, если она до сих пор осталась, я её тоже залью на платформу, если вдруг сможете ответить, буду предельно благодарен вдвойне))